# QML Set FileDialog folder property to valid path but not adhered to

Tags: qt, qml

When my QML `FIleDialog` opens I want it to open in a specific directory. But it's not doing so. It always opens in the directory the .exe is executing from.

I have set the QML property `folder` to a valid directory but its not working. If I set `folder` to `shortcuts.home` it does work.

Can you provide advice on whats wrong?

```
FileDialog {
    id: fileDialog
    title: "Please choose a file"
    folder: "D:/_Work/foo/bar/" // Note shortcuts.home does work
    nameFilters: [ "Image files (*.jpg *.png)", "All files (*)" ]
    onAccepted: {
        image.source = fileDialog.fileUrl
    }
    onRejected: {
        console.log("Canceled")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are `shortcuts.home` and `D:/_Work/foo/bar/` the same folder?

Comment: @folibis no they are different.

Comment: Have you tried adding the prefix `file:///` to your folder path like this; `file:///D:/_Work/foo/bar/`

Answer (score 1):

Type of the `FileDialog` [folder](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#folder-prop) property is [url](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-url.html). Now you are binding a local file path to that property. You can make a local file path a url by adding `file:///` (Windows) or `file://` (Linux/Mac) in front of the file path.

Note: `shortcuts.home` will provide the `url` of the user's home directory.

Comment: This is very bad approach to do, adding file:/// is way how to encounter a lot of edge cases. Use this QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)

Comment: @JiriOtoupalイりオトウパー unfortunately that's not available from QML side. In order to call QUrl::fromLocalFile from QML you need to write your own C++ wrapper for it and register it to QML context.

Comment: Yes i know, or Python wrapper if you use PySide